# How to bind the ConverterParameter property of a binding to a DependencyProperty

Tags: wpf, binding, ivalueconverter

I'm building a `UserControl` for my WPF application which will allow the user to navigate through pages of data returned by a search.  I have to reduce my application's memory usage and, depending on the critieria, a search can return lots of data.

The window contains a Telerik `RadGridView` control now and will contain an instance of this new `UserControl`.  The new control will have buttons for going back to the first page of data, the previous page, another for the next page, and one more for the last page, as well as a `ComboBox` for going to a particular page number.

I want to enable or disable the buttons such that the first page button and the previous page button are enabled only if the current page isn't the first, and the next page button and the last page button are enabled only if the current isn't the last.

Now, I have created two classes that implement `IValueConverter` in my application which do comparisons.  They compare the `value` parameter to the `Parameter` argument in the `Convert` method.  This works OK for the First and Previous Page buttons, since I'm comparing to zero.  It's the Next and Last Page buttons where this may fall apart.

The `UserControl` has a `DependencyProperty` that represents the number of pages of data that match the query criteria.  I have an `IValueConverter` that returns `true` if the `value` argument is less than the `parameter` argument.  Can I bind the ConvertParameter property of the `Binding` to the number pages `DependencyProperty`?  Or do I have to add another property that indicates it's ok to enable these buttons?

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to abuse the IValueConverter to convert multiple values to a single one. Use an implementation of `IMultiValueConverter` for this and use it like so.

```
    <MultiBinding Converter="{your IMultiValueConverter implementation}"
                  Mode="OneWay">
        <Binding Path="Property1" />
        <Binding Path="Property2" />
    </MultiBinding>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx